# Data of struct created at return statement of a function is available in caller function

Tags: c, struct, static, return-value

I wrote the following program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int num1;
    int num2;
} two_ints;


two_ints func() {
    return (two_ints){.num1 = 1, .num2 = 2};
}

int main() {
    two_ints nums = func();
    printf("%d %d", nums.num1, nums.num2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code WORKS for some reason. It prints 1 and 2. What I want to know is will it work every time? What I mean is, does the compiler do something to make the struct returned static, since it is supposed to be returned.

Thank You.

Comment: Why would it need to be static? You're not returning a pointer, you're returning a structure. Return values are copied.

Comment: You can return a structure by value in C, the returned data is a hard copy of the local data inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
two_ints nums = func();
```

you declared an object nums of the type two_ints with the automatic storage duration and initialized it by the temporary object returned by the function. So now the data member num1 and the data member num2 of the object nums contain correspondingly 1 and 2.

So the program is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

When you return a struct, it makes a copy, so there's no need for it to be static. Your function is essentially short for this:

```
two_ints func() {
    two_ints temp = {.num1 = 1, .num2 = 2};
    return temp;
}
```